# How could I share scope method with other models using Rails 4 and mongoind

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

How could I share scope method with other models using Rails 4 and mongoind

if put `scope` in `included do`, the error was

> NoMethodError: undefined method `scope' for User:Class

if put `scope` in `module ClassMethods`, the error was

> NoMethodError: undefined method `scope' for RecentlySearch::ClassMethods:Module

## Code snippet

```
class User
  include RecentlySearch
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :history, type: Array
end
```

## snippert 2

```
module RecentlySearch
extend ActiveSupport::Concern

module ClassMethods
  scope :hi, -> {p 'hi'}
end

included do
  scope :hi, -> {p 'hi'}

end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scope` class method comes from `Mongoid::Document` so when you:

```
include RecentlySearch
```

there is no `scope` method yet. You need to include `Mongoid::Document` first:

```
include Mongoid::Document
include RecentlySearch
```